# preventing other android apps/developers making requests to my service with facebook_id and access token using OAuth2 client_id and client secret

Tags: android, facebook, web-services, facebook-graph-api, oauth

So i am using **facebook** login in my android app with facebook lite, i have an app server that i send the users **facebook id** and **access token** sent gotten from facebook, then my **app server** will verify the credentials on facebook and grant access to the user.

the obvious problem is that any other app or developer can use facebook_ids and access tokens to access my app server and also authenticate, so i was thinking that i'll send my **client_id and client_secret** **(OAuth2 implementation)** along with the facebook_id and access token to my app server, as the client secret and client id are unique to my app server and shared between my app client and server.

Just want to know thoughts on this and what's the best course of action.

Comment: You should not expose the client secret in client-side code, if at all avoidable. Just pass the access token to the server, and debug it there. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling

Comment: @CBroe but that does not solve the problem of having other developers access my service with an access token or facebook_id....and whats the best way to package client secret and client id (OAuth 2.0) with an app in production

Comment: Only access tokens belonging to your app can be debugged by your app.

Comment: tx for the link, ok so the input token is the one generated for a user of my app, didnt get the access token part tho....

Comment: You take the access token you get from the login flow on the mobile device and send it to your server, where you validate that the token was indeed issued for your app.

Comment: ok tx a lot for you help